# How do I extract an object's data within an object in php?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I need to get the result data "vaild" under the Verification object. This line (["result"]=> string(5) "valid" ). It appears to be an object within an object and I cannot find the syntax as to how to access the data within that.

```
object(EmailCheck\Object\ResponseObject)#25 (1) { 
    ["response":protected]=> array(6) { 
        ["status"]=> string(7) "success" 
        ["total_results"]=> int(6) 
        ["total_pages"]=> int(1) 
        ["query"]=> array(8) { 
            ["job_id"]=> int(2562625) 
            ["valids"]=> int(1) 
            ["invalids"]=> int(1) 
            ["disposables"]=> int(1) 
            ["catchalls"]=> int(1) 
            ["unknowns"]=> int(1) 
            ["page"]=> int(0) 
            ["items_per_page"]=> int(10) 
        } 
        ["results"]=> array(6) { 
            [0]=> array(2) {     
                ["data"]=> array(4) { 
                    ["email"]=> string(20) "chris@example.com" 
                    [0]=> string(1) "1" 
                    ["ID"]=> string(1) "1" 
                    ["EMAIL"]=> string(20) "chris@example.com" 
                    } 
                ["verification"]=> object(EmailCheck\Object\VerificationObject)#7 (1) { 
                    ["response":protected]=> array(7) { 
                        ["result"]=> string(5) "valid" 
                        ["flags"]=> array(3) { 
                            [0]=> string(7) "has_dns" 
                            [1]=> string(10) "has_dns_mx" 
                            [2]=> string(16) "smtp_connectable" 
                        } 
                ["suggested_correction"]=> string(0) "" 
                ["address_info"]=> object(EmailCheck\Object\ResponseObject)#9 (1) { 
                    ["response":protected]=> array(9) { 
                        ["original_email"]=> string(20) "chris@example.com" 
                        ["normalized_email"]=> string(20) "chris@example.com" 
                        ["addr"]=> string(6) "chris" 
                        ["alias"]=> string(0) "" ["host"]=> string(13) "example.com" 
                        ["fqdn"]=> string(13) "example.com" 
                        ["domain"]=> string(9) "example" 
                        ["subdomain"]=> string(0) "" 
                        ["tld"]=> string(3) "com" 
                    } 
                } 
                ["email"]=> string(20) "chris@example.com 
                ["result_integer"]=> int(0) 
                ["credits_info"]=> object(EmailCheck\Object\ResponseObject)#8 (1) { 
                    ["response":protected]=> array(0) { 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

The data i need is in this part of the code:

```
["verification"]=> object(EmailCheck\Object\VerificationObject)#7 (1) { 
                ["response":protected]=> array(7) { 
                    ["result"]=> string(5) "valid" 
                    ["flags"]=> array(3) { 
                        [0]=> string(7) "has_dns" 
                        [1]=> string(10) "has_dns_mx" 
                        [2]=> string(16) "smtp_connectable" 
                    }
```

I can get the email out of data using this:

```
$object->results[$counter]['data']['email']
```

Comment: Can you show some of your attempts? Does adapting your previous solution not work? `$object->results[$counter]["verification"]->response["result"]`

Comment: Nope, this does not work. I've tried countless variations...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
$object->results[$counter]['verification']->result
```